# How do I use PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I can't seem to get my module and class files to load from my script, but it loads fine from the REPL

I have a fairly simply project structure

```
/home/user/project/
/home/user/project/bin/
/home/user/project/bin/myscript.py
/home/user/project/lib/
/home/user/project/lib/mymodule/__init__.py
/home/user/project/lib/mymodule/example.py
```

When I run the Python REPL, everything runs just fine.

```
$export PYTHONPATH=./lib:$PYTHONPATH # Making sure that the REPL and script have access
$python
Python 2.7.8 blashblahblah
...
>from mymodule.example import MyClass
>test = MyClass()
>^D
$./bin/myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mymodule.example import MyClass
  File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mymodule.example import MyClass
ImportError: No module named example
```

Comment: What about `python bin/myscript.py`? Is *PYTHONPATH* set when you run the script directly? Try `print(sys.path)` at the beginning of the file, it will most likely clear things up.

Comment: In the above code, I have set and exported pythonpath appropriately. I have also tried using an absolute system path rather than a relative one. PYTHONPATH is clearly set correctly for the REPL, as resetting my pythonpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question here.
It turns out that the scripts name was 'mymodule.py'

```
bin/
bin/mymodule.py
lib/
lib/mymodule/
lib/mymodule/__init__.py
lib/mymodule/example.py
```

When importing from the repl, the pythonpath resolves to the lib/mymodule module, and the code is loaded correctly (mostly). When running the script `mymodule.py`, the python interpreter *prepends the script's directory `bin/` to the pythonpath*. **The script then sees an import statement(s) for mymodule, and sources itself.** When it fails to find a namespace that can be traversed to look for 'example' within the script, it throws the ImportError.

The solution is to either rename the module or rename the script, (e.g. `bin/my_module.py`) so that the namespaces don't collide.